# Can Someone tell me how to put a .text file in to a dictionary containing a number and a string with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

I am making a project about a contact saver but I am not able to read a single contact in the code...
Please help me...
I am giving the code and the problem
If you can **please** provide me with the whole part of finding the single user or all the related users...
Thanks...

```
what = input("Do you want to read a single contact(y, n): ")
if what == 'y':
    who = input("Please Enter the name: ")
    a = open('contacts.txt', 'a')
    for line in a:
        k, v = line.strip().split('=')
        users[k.strip()] = v.strip()
        a.close()

    for i in users:
        if who.lower() == i.lower() or i.startswith(who[:3]):
            print(i)
```

and this is the error:
'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Teerth Jain/Desktop/teerth_made_projects/contacts.py", line 18, in 
    for line in a:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable enter code here

'

Answer (score 0):

You've opened the file in a writing mode as opposed to a reading mode, use `"r"` instead of `"a"` (which is append to file)

```
a = open('contacts.txt', 'r')
```

Also, not sure if you've included your question's indentation correctly, but the `a.close()` should be outside the for loop

As noted in the comments, using `with` is preferred over explicitly closing the file.

```
with open('contacts.txt', "r") as a:
    for line in a:
        k, v = line.strip().split('=')
        users[k.strip()] = v.strip()
```

Comment: `r` is the default, can just be `open(...)`. also, better practice to use `with` than calling `close`

Comment: @DeepSpace - I agree, I explicitly included the `"r"` to make sure its clear what `open` is doing whlist the op is still learning.

Comment: I have done that still it's not happening...The error is `  k, v = line.strip().split('=')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: @Teerthjain - Thats a different issue, namely you have a line in your file that can't be split

Comment: Someone please answer my question fast...please